# regex query to find numbers after matching section

Tags: regular-expression

```
instance=hostname1, topic=“AB_CD_EF_12345_ZY_XW_001_000001”
instance=hostname2, topic=“AB_CD_EF_1345_ZY_XW_001_00001”
instance=hostname1, topic=“AB_CD_EF_1235_ZY_XW_001_000001”
instance=hostname2, topic=“AB_CD_EF_GH_4567_ZY_XW_01_000001”
instance=hostname1, topic=“AB_CD_EF_35678_ZY_XW_001_00001”
instance=hostname2, topic=“AB_CD_EF_56789_ZY_XW_001_000001”
```

I tried with below details, they work good as a separate query :

```
/*.topic="AB_CD_EF_([^_]+).*/

12345
1345
1235

/*.topic="AB_CD_EF_GH_([^_]+).*/

4567
35678
56789
```

I need a regex which can give me out as :

```
12345
1345
1235
4567
35678
56789
```

Please help , thanks

Comment: In what way is the regex used? In other words, what command are you using it with? Examples would be `sed`, `awk`, `grep`.

Comment: @SuS : I tried to fix the formatting issue in your question; please, check if now looks like what you were trying to write.

Comment: Something's odd with your quotation marks. The input data is using `“` and `”` and in your regexes you're using `"`. And your regexes start with `/*.` and I guess you mean `/.*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure precisely what flavour of regex you are using, but if you want to combine both the following regexes

```
/*.topic="AB_CD_EF_([^_]+).*/
/*.topic="AB_CD_EF_GH_([^_]+).*/
```

i.e. you want to match *either* regex, you can make the `GH_` part optional using `?`.

```
/*.topic="AB_CD_EF_(GH_)?([^_]+).*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much Spahawk sharing answer . It worked .

Hi Freddy, sorry for confusion , this regex is for Grafana and for some reason, regex works differently there . 

All suggestions helped to sort out the regex .

Comment: No worries. Welcome to U/L! Just to let you know, you can say thank you on this site by accepting the answer (clicking the tick on the left) and optionally upvote (click the up arrow). Cheers!